# Default or zero value of unknown template type

Tags: c++, templates, default, default-value

Assuming the template function

```
template<typename T>
T foo(){
  // ...
  // Error occured
  if(error)
     return 0;
  // ...
}
```

which should return `0`, `0.0f`, `nullptr`, ... depending on the type `T`, when an error occured.

How to get the `0` of a unknown template type?
in C# you can write `default(T)` to do this.

How to perform this in C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) like `return T();` or `return T{};` (since C++11), or just `return {};` (see [list initialization (since C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)) to return the default value of `T`.

Comment: Which one would you prefer?

Comment: @Matthias `return T();` and `return T{};` have the same effect here, either looks fine to me. `return {};` is the shortest one, you might want to use it.